# Laravel 5.6 Change email field name as username for forgot password

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I changed email field name for forgot password as username. but when i submit the form it is showing me following error.

```
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' (SQL: delete from `password_resets` where `email` = example@gmail.com)"
```

So in which file i need to change email with username?

Answer (score 0):

- change 'email to 'username' in your `auth.passwords.email' view

in you ForgotPasswordController

```
public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
        $this->validate($request, ['username' => 'required'], ['username.required' => 'Please enter your username.']);

         $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
            $request->only('username')
        );

        if ($response === Password::RESET_LINK_SENT) {
            return back()->with('status', trans($response));
        }

        return back()->withErrors(
            ['email' => trans($response)]
        );
}
```

Comment: Hi Masoud Haghbin..
I changed it but still i get same error.

Comment: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' (SQL: delete from `password_resets` where `email` = example@gmail.com)" the same error.

Comment: can you tell me where delete query perform after submit username?